# How to change postgres docker image wal level on setup?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am using the postgres:11.6-alpine image for one of my applications and I would like to set the image wal_level to 'logical' on setup, preferably using docker-compose.

The solutions I found needs you to overwrite the image postgresql.conf. However I dont want to have a full postgresql.conf file just to change this setting.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Update the `command` portion of your PostgreSQL container configuration like so.

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:11.6-alpine
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=my_db
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=changeme
    command:
      - "postgres"
      - "-c"
      - "wal_level=logical"
```

Or

```
    command: [ "postgres", "-c", "wal_level=logical" ]
```

If you prefer that formatting.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore I get the error: `"root" execution of the PostgreSQL server is not permitted.
The server must be started under an unprivileged user ID to prevent
possible system security compromise.  See the documentation for
more information on how to properly start the server.`

Comment: Yeah, looks like wal_level=logical does not exist anymore. Couldn't find any documentation on dropping this though.

Comment: This command override with wal_level=logical worked for me on postgres:14.7 Docker image.